# How do I get an image to show up actual size?

Tags: css

I have an image in a div that my images are max size of 40%. How do I get the image to be actual size?

```
.v-guide img {
    width: 40%;
    border: 1px black solid;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 12px 0 0;
    }
```

This is the style I have. How can I add a style in the img tag to have the image actual style, or even max-size of 80%?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `max-width` to the style and don't force its width with `width`.

```css
img {
  max-width: 80%;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x150">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/10000x150">
  </div>
</div>
```